# Cannot we initialize a variable in constructor as follows? [Angular2]

Tags: angular

I just started learning angular-2. The string "Pikolo" does not show up in the end-html, when the class appcomponent is as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
    mideos:String;
    construtor(){
        this.mideos = "Pikolo";
    }
}
```

I do not think there is a  problem with passing the variable thru components and/or binding with html because the value appears,  when I change the code as follows:

```
export class AppComponent {
    mideos:String = "Pikolo";
    construtor(){

    }
}
```

I am really confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `construtor` is this a typo?

Comment: Thanks a lot... that was the problem the whole time.. silly me

Comment: Always check console, it would of told you about the typo

Comment: @Huangism it wouldn't generate an error in this case.. `construtor` has consider as normal javsascript function..

Comment: @PankajParkar there is no such thing as `construtor` only `constructor`

Comment: @Huangism yes I know, but typescript compiler wouldn't throw an error for `construtor` and `construtor` is considered as general function..

Comment: @PankajParkar oh yes I see what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular2 Component's constructor specifically for DI purposes,Initializing a property in the constructor allows you to leverage constructor parameters when you're initializing the property.

There is no difference in generated JS between the two.

**EDIT:**
your code has a typo error

```
export class AppComponent {
    mideos:String;
    constructor(){
        this.mideos = "Pikolo";
    }
}
```